# Two fields in one - tables in dynamics AX

Tags: field, axapta, x++

I have to create method for table in Dynamics AX which concatenate two fields from one table in one field. For example Name+Surname displays in one field. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create [`display` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx#Anchor_0) like this:

```
public display PersonName fullName()
{
    return this.FirstName + ' ' + this.LastName;
}
```

See also [`edit` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa637541.aspx).

Comment: Tip for other: PersonName is a EDT ;)

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate two fields (or more) you can use `StrFmt()` method.

***Example:***

```
str fullName;    

fullName = strFmt("%1 %2", this.Name, this.Surname);
```